# Udev rules are not working for libusb on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, libusb, udev

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, x86_64.

I've a usb device that uses libusb to communicate with the computer.
Once I plug it into the computer and run the communication program I get the following error:

```
libusb couldn't open USB device /dev/bus/usb/008/004: Permission denied.
libusb requires write access to USB device nodes.
libusb failed to find the Optotrak USB device.  Are you sure you have set the udev permissions correctly?
```

So if I chmod the /dev/bus/usb/008/004 as follows:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/bus/usb/008/004
```

and run the communication program again, then the device works perfectly.
The problem is that every time I plug the device, the last number changes, so I should have to chmod every time the usb bus, but since not all users know the administrator password this is a problem.

So the manufacturer suggest to edit the udev rules as follows. Create a 12-ndi-rules inside /etc/udev/rules.d :

```
BUS=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0403", SYSFS{idProduct}=="da77", GROUP="plugdev"
```

(I've checked with lsusb that SYSFS are correct)

```
lsusb 

Bus 008 Device 004: ID 0403:da77 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
```

and then reload the rules:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

but still the permissions for bus 008/004 are not correctly set.

How do I make these rules permament at every reboot? I would also like to get make them permanent also if I change the port of the usb device.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have a really old udev, the rule is wrong, it should be :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", ATTR{idProduct}=="da77", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Putting the rule in a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d/` is the correct way to make it permanent.

Other things you can put in a rule file are [in the man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev/udev.html).

Comment: It definitely works, but only after a reboot of the system. Reloading the rules doesn't seem to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @linello It will work after unloading and loading the module for your device (assuming it is loadable module). You do not necessarily have to reboot the system. Example for a network device, I do `rmmod ixgbe`, `rmmod tg3`,`rmmod e1000` then `modprobe ixgbe`, `modprobe tg3`,`modprobe e1000` depending on type of network driver.

Comment: The other thing that I also noticed is that if I choose lower number e.g. `25-<rule name>.rules` then if that rule exists in say `65-<rule name 1>.rules` the higher number, in this case `65-<rule name 1>.rules`, takes precedence over lower number, in this case `25-<rule name>.rules`. Hence as a rule I choose to start naming convention > 95

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS I found: `idVendor` and `idProduct` matches are *case-sensitive*, so above, ="DA77" doesn't work for me but ="da77" does. (Diagnosed via `udevadm info --attribute-walk /dev/bus/usb/008/023` where bus 008 and device 023 are just examples; `lsusb` will tell you yours.) After changing the rules, `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules` and then `sudo udevadm trigger` avoids a reboot: changes will take effect several seconds *after* the second command completes.

Answer (score 11):

OK here are all the steps to get this to work. I had problems with all responses I found online, bits and pieces everywhere without any certain order and no single working solution, (running Android Studio, Jmonkey 3D, and Ubuntu 14.04)

If **adb devices** shows android device as **?????????** (no permissions) follow these instructions:

1) create file **/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules**

```
sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

2) copy and paste contents below:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e79", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="091e", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="24e3", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2116", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"    
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0409", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2080", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2257", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10a9", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d4d", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0471", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04da", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1f53", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0930", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

3) Run the following command to change file permissions:

```
sudo chmod a+r /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
```

4) connect your phone via usb and run the following command:

```
lsusb
```

Look for your device(s) Example (Nexus 5):

> Bus 003 Device 074: ID **18d1**:4ee7 Google Inc.

For **Nexus 5**, Vendor ID is **18d1**, mine is on Bus "**003**"

5) Now reload the rules with the following commands:

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
sudo service udev restart
sudo udevadm trigger
```

6) Verify device is now allowing **plugdev** user group access

```
ls -l /dev/bus/usb/<bus number from step 4>
```

Example:

```
ls -l /dev/bus/usb/003

crw-rw-rw- 1 root plugdev 189, 329 Jul  3 18:23 074
```

7) Run **adb devices** to confirm permissions are correct and enjoy!

**Note:** if you haven't created the **plugdev** group and **added your user name** to it (if permission denied prepend "sudo" following commands):

1) add plugdev group:

```
groupadd plugdev
```

2) add your **username** to **plugdev** group (useradd -G {group-name} username):

```
useradd -G plugdev billy
```

3) restart udev (you may need to log off and log back in to update user group):

```
sudo service udev restart
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also working in more or less the same thing and to do the reload I have the same problem using that function, but if you were to use

```
udevadm trigger
```

It will actually reload the rules
Also, I don't know if you already did so, I think you have to add the users to the group you created

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the user is not part of the group that was granted access by the udev rules.
To add the (existing) user, to (existing) group plugdev, you should do this:

```
sudo usermod -a -G groupName userName
```

Answer (score 0):

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", ATTR{idProduct}=="da77", GROUP="plugdev"`

> Putting the rule in a file in /etc/udev/rules.d/ is the correct way to make it permanent.

Only it helped me to run Qt Creator with permission for USB exchange (dev/usb/hiddev0) under Debian 11 with LXQt!