# Permissions on HID device. Why is my udev rule being ignored?

Tags: linux, usb, hid, udev

First, I do not understand why I am having to ask this question.  I am running as root, and root is part of the "plugdev" group.

I am trying to add a MagTek USB-Magstripe reader to my Linux system and it is not working.  When I try and output >> to a file I get "permission denied".  When I "cd /dev/usb" and "ls -la" I see:

crw-------  1 root root 180, 0 Jul  5 10:52 hiddev0

And I can chmod it to 666 or 777 but when I plug it back in it reverts back to its old permissions.  So looking around the web I came up with the following from udevadm and created 99-rules.local in /etc/udev/rules.d :

SUBSYSTEM="usbmisc", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002", ATTRS{serial}=="0000:04:00.0", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/chmod 777 /dev/$name"

"service udev restart" does not work, logging out does not work, rebooting my system does not work.  Whatever I do this device defaults back to its old permissions.

Ideally, I would like *ALL USB* devices to be 755 by default.  I don't understand why this is so difficult to achieve and why I can't do this by default anyway as root?

Answer (score 0):

run `lsusb` and `dmesg` to get more information of the magstripe reader (see this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68588/fixed-udev-rules-for-usb-modems). Get the USB *Vendor ID* and *Product ID* and try to create the udev rule like in this [Udev rules are not working for libusb on Ubuntu 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25445178/udev-rules-are-not-working-for-libusb-on-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1)

`SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0403", ATTR{idProduct}=="da77", GROUP="plugdev`

place the file in `/etc/udev/udev.d`

https://dentrassi.de/2014/11/03/identify-gsm-modem-devices-using-udev/